# How to replace unknown strings?

Tags: regex, ansible

I am working on a playbook and I need to find out a way to replace some specific values (like in the bellow example) for values I will have in variables. The problem is, the values to be replace will be different every time I run the playbook.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'somestring' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'somevalue' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'someothervalue' );
```

I am considering the module `ansible.builtin.replace` or even the module `shell` but I still couldn't figure out a way to make it work. I am new to ansible and IT in general and kind of still don't understand how regular expressions work.

I was trying like this but as you can see, I have absolute no idea what I am doing:

```yaml
- name: Replace between the expressions (requires Ansible >= 2.4)
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /home/marcelo/public_html/wp-config.php
    after: "define( 'DB_NAME', '"
    before: "');"
    regexp: "*"
    replace: "{{ DBNM }}"
```

Some suggestions or examples I could use to start from would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the replace-module is the way to go. You are already thinking in the right way with `after` and `before`, but those match the whole line, not part of it (you can by this specify a part in a file where the replace should be happening).
In your case, you need to pack all the logic into the regexp:

```yaml
- name: Replace between the expressions (requires Ansible >= 2.4)
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /home/marcelo/public_html/wp-config.php
    regexp: "define\\( 'DB_NAME', '.*' \\);"
    replace: "define( 'DB_NAME', '{{ DBNM }}' );"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @toydarian! It worked like a charm!

Comment: Great! Please click the tick-button next to my answer to mark it as accepted, @MJG  :)

Comment: Done, @toydarian! Sorry, I am also new to stackoverflow!